# SSRS Selective Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, filtering, grouping

I have some data where I can setup a grouping on a field.   One of the values of the group is NULL.   I want to exclude the Null from grouping data that has a NULL value for the grouping field.   However, I still need to display that data.

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly do you want to do this given your report contains a groupping but you still want to show the data?  This is not possible.

Comment: Any chance you can add a small example data set and the resulting grid you're after?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get what you are looking for,, but it seems you don't want the `NULL` value being show, still you want the data the `NULL` group displays.
 - 1st solution: You could use `isNULL()` function in SQL query so it will show any other value you want  replacing the `NULL` in the report.
 - 2nd solution: Like a `isNULL()` function in SQL Server, but in SSRS [Check For Null Column Value in an expression.](http://www.mredkj.com/vbnet/RSNullCheck.html)